# 0 < 0 -1 is true?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocoa

I understand that something is wrong with type convertations, from my perspective this is really weard:

months is NSArray
so I have no items there:
months.count == 0

this doesn't work like it should appears 0 < 0 -1 is true?

```
(0 < months.count -1) == true
```

but this works fine

```
(0 < (int)months.count -1) == false
```

Don't get why?

Comment: Is it fair to simplify your examples to: `0 < 0-1 == true` and `0 < 0-1 == false` ?

Comment: @sarnold - actually, I think not... as `0-1` is signed, and `months.count -1` is unsigned

Answer (score 4, accepted):

count returns NSUInteger, which is unsigned, so `months.count -1` is an unsigned expression and is evaluated to positive number, and therefore bigger than 0.

when you cast it to int, the expression `(int)months.count -1` is evaluated as signed, and therefore equals to -1, which is smaller than 0.

Comment: ok this means, (unsigned)0 - (int)1 == (unsigned)0
but then why (signed)0 < (unsigned)0 is true?

Comment: `(signed)0 < (unsigned)0` is not true, `(signed)0 < (unsigned)0 - 1` is true. they are totaly different expressions.

Comment: from my understanding, compiler should count right part and left part. in the end it should be like (signed) 0 vs (unsigned)0

Comment: You forget the  `-1` it has precedence over `<`. see http://www.swansontec.com/sopc.html

Comment: Hahaha, ok I've got it. (unsigned)0 - 1 = (unsigned)4294967295

Answer (score 1):

From the [NSArray documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSArray_Class/NSArray.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSArray/count), we can see that the `count` method returns a NSUInteger, which is an *unsigned* integer.  By subtracting 1 from an unsigned 0, we end up with the largest possible unsigned integer you can actually get.

Comment: same thing, why then (signed)0 < (unsigned)0 ?

Comment: @IgorR.: It isn't. 0 == 0, regardless of types.